# Const method with new c++ return value syntax

Tags: c++

it's a simple question but i don't find answer.

I start to work with the new c++ return value syntax. For example :

```
class A
{ 
    // Old syntax
    float foo();

    // New syntax 
    auto foo() ->float;
};
```

But i don't know how to do the same thing for const method

```
class A
    { 
        // Old syntax
        float foo() const;

        // New syntax 
        auto foo() ->float const;
    };
```

Always detecting as returning const float. If someone know how to write correctly  this kind of method, thank you in advance.

Comment: Yikes. This 'new syntax' looks like a correction for something that never needed a correction. Which standard introduces that?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen C++11, but... The standard doesn't expect you to do it in this case. The `->` syntax is useful in some cases when the return type has to depend on a template parameter, IIRC. It is also not mandatory, if the declaration is the definition you can just omit `->` and use `auto`... which can be useful :)

Comment: If by "new" you mean 7 years old...

Comment: @Asu thanks for clarification :) I knew that's the syntax for lambdas (even though it's mostly omitted), but I never seen it in use for a function.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I mean, it can actually be useful. If you have multiple return paths it means you can do `[&] () -> SomeLongType<BlahBlah> { if (thingie) { return {42}; } else { return {360}; } }`... which applies to this case too

Comment: @Yksisarvinen it's really useful when your return type is dependant on deduced parameters `template<typename A, typename B> decltype(std::declval<A>() + std::declval<B>()) do_stuff(A a, B b)` becomes `template<typename A, typename B> auto do_stuff (A a, B b) -> decltype(a + b)` because you can refer to the parameter names. Similarly it helps with member types `MyClass::MyType MyClass::do_stuff()` becomes `auto MyClass::do_stuff() -> MyType`

Comment: @Caleth Thanks! Much clearer now :)

Answer (score 3):

`auto foo() const -> float;` is the syntax.

The return type is `float`, **not** `const float`, and the function itself is a `const` member.

Note that you are allowed to use one format in the declaration and the other in the definition.